# Compare the difference on rows where two columns match SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the difference of [sales] for every [name] comparing the current [date] VS the previous [date]

this is what I got:

| name | date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ana | 12/15 | 100 |
| Joseph | 12/15 | 150 |
| Carl | 12/15 | 50 |
| ana | 12/14 | 20 |
| Joseph | 12/14 | 50 |
| Carl | 12/14 | 200 |
| ana | 12/13 | 50 |
| Joseph | 12/13 | 300 |
| Carl | 12/13 | 100 |

this is the output that I'm looking for:

| name | date | sales | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ana | 12/15 | 100 | 80 |
| Joseph | 12/15 | 150 | 100 |
| Carl | 12/15 | 50 | -150 |
| ana | 12/14 | 20 | -30 |
| Joseph | 12/14 | 50 | -250 |
| Carl | 12/14 | 200 | 100 |
| ana | 12/13 | 50 | 0 |
| Joseph | 12/13 | 300 | 0 |
| Carl | 12/13 | 100 | 0 |

I'm new on the SQL server and I think that I need to use the CASE statement, appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to use `LAG(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [date])`, if I have time I'll post an answer in a bit, or someone will beat me to it. That will get you the previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using window functions :

```
SELECT *  
  ,sales - LAG(sales,1,sales) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) AS difference
FROM #test
ORDER BY name , date
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is `LAG` partition over the `name`, with the default value defined (which is the 3rd parameter). I also **assume** your column `date` is a `date` (because with a name like that why wouldn't it be) despite your sample data suggesting it isn't (and if it isn't, that needs fixing):

```sql
SELECT name,
       date,
       sales,
       sales - LAG(sales,1,sales) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date ASC) as difference
FROM (VALUES('ana    ',CONVERT(date,'2/15/2020',101), 100),
            ('Joseph ',CONVERT(date,'2/15/2020',101), 150),
            ('Carl   ',CONVERT(date,'2/15/2020',101), 50),
            ('ana    ',CONVERT(date,'2/14/2020',101), 20),
            ('Joseph ',CONVERT(date,'2/14/2020',101), 50),
            ('Carl   ',CONVERT(date,'2/14/2020',101), 200),
            ('ana    ',CONVERT(date,'2/13/2020',101), 50),
            ('Joseph ',CONVERT(date,'2/13/2020',101), 300),
            ('Carl   ',CONVERT(date,'2/13/2020',101), 100))YourTable(name,date,sales)
ORDER BY date DESC,
         name ASC;
```